# MySQL Incorrect DateTime Value for Date older than 1980

Tags: mysql, timestamp, mysqlimport

While, trying to import a .sql file into my database, I am getting the following error for one of the insert statements -

```
ERROR 1292 (22007) at line 31504: Incorrect datetime value: '1936-01-31 00:00:00' for column 'BatchDate' at row 1. Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

I am facing this error only for dates older than 1980. and its happening only while I am trying to import the dump through import statement or through WorkBench. If I execute the statement alone, it works fine. Here is the table structure and the insert statement

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BatchEntry`;

CREATE TABLE `BatchEntry` (
  `BatchNo` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `BatchDate` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  `BTax_ID` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0, 
  `BPayor_No` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0, 
  `BBroker_No` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0, 
  `BHam_Cont` VARCHAR(4), 
  `BInv_Org_Date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  `BInv_Due_Date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  `BDate_Adv` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  `BRec_Amt` DECIMAL(19,4) DEFAULT 0, 
  `BPaymnt_Com` LONGTEXT, 
  `BTrans_Count` INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
  `BPrefix` VARCHAR(10), 
  `BStartNumber` INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
  `BSuffix` VARCHAR(10), 
  `BCreated` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0, 
  `BAdvMethod` INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
  INDEX (`BPayor_No`), 
  INDEX (`BTax_ID`), 
  PRIMARY KEY (`BatchNo`)
) ENGINE=myisam DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `BatchEntry` (`BatchNo`, `BatchDate`, `BTax_ID`, `BPayor_No`, `BBroker_No`, `BHam_Cont`, `BInv_Org_Date`, `BInv_Due_Date`, `BDate_Adv`, `BRec_Amt`, `BPaymnt_Com`, `BTrans_Count`, `BPrefix`, `BStartNumber`, `BSuffix`, `BCreated`, `BAdvMethod`) VALUES (1396, '1936-01-31 00:00:00', 561986585, 4528, 749, 'BSR', '2005-12-30 00:00:00', '2006-01-30 00:00:00', '2006-01-31 00:00:00', 0, NULL, 14, 'MC', 24850, NULL, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Batchdate is not a DATETIME column but a TIMESTAMP column. The range for TIMESTAMP doesn't include this date:

```
CREATE TABLE `BatchEntry` (
  `BatchNo` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `BatchDate` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,    -- it's TIMESTAMP
```

and the error message is

> Incorrect datetime value: '1936-01-31 00:00:00'

That is older than '1970-01-01 00:00:01', out of range of the data type  `TIMESTAMP`

[The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html)

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and
>   time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to
>   '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

**Solution**

Change the data type to `DATETIME`.

```
CREATE TABLE `BatchEntry` (
  `BatchNo` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `BatchDate` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  [...]
```

If you're using MySQL 5.6.5 or newer then you could change the datatype to DATETIME, because since this version DATETIME supports the automatic initialization too. You seem to use a newer version, since you're using more than one such column with automatic initialization. This feature was added at the same time.

[Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically
>   initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the
>   current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and
>   for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table.

**Note**

For date values in the 1970s it will work too.

Comment: Thanks you very much. It works!! However, what is the explanation behind the fact that it works when I execute the statement only and does not work while importing the dump.

Comment: If you're executing the single command, you get your message as a warning and if you're selecting the row you will find that there's the special value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' that indicates an invalid value: *Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00 00:00:00').* from [The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html)